# How can I store a part of an array to another array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to write a svm code, but i am literally a beginner in matlab.

So in my code, in a for loop, i should store predictions. The data is like this:

```
testIdx =  [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]';  % i wrote it like this but it says logical
```

and

```
pred = [1 1 1 0 1 0]'; % again logical
```

So i want to form a 12 length array and turn its 1st,2nd,3rd,9th,11th,12th elements into `1 1 1 0 1 0`, and likewise rest of test elements into another set of 0/1s in other iteration.

If possible let it be a normal array, not logical. Thanks in advance

I did it myself old style but there must be a shorter direct way right?

```
Y = zeros ( size(testIdx,1), 1) ;
a=1;

for i = 1:size(testIdx,1)
    if testIdx(i) ==1
        Y(i) = pred(a);
        a=a+1;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create `testIdx` and `pred` the way you specified, then they are `double` and not `logical` type. To use logical indexing, it is easiest if `testIdx` is converted to the `logical` type. Then you can simply use

```
testIdx =  [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]';
pred = [1 1 1 0 1 0]';

Y = zeros(size(testIdx));
Y(logical(testIdx)) = pred;
```

With `Y(logical(testIdx)`, you select all indexes which are set to `1` in the `testIdx` vector and then write `pred`to these indexes.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help. If this solves your problem, I'd appreciate if you could accept the answer. Thank you.